# How to generate UUID with vidibus-uuid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, uuid

I am trying to generate an UUID associated with my Domain model using vidibus-uuid. This means that every time a new domain gets created, a randomly generated UUID is created as well. Currently, I am using Mongoid with Rails and have the following Domain model:

```
class Domain
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Vidibus::Uuid::Mongoid
  field :name, type: String
  field :url, type: String
  field :domain_uuid
  validates :domain_uuid, :uuid => {:allow_blank => true}

  belongs_to :user
end
```

My Domain Controller looks like this for the creating a new domain:

```
def create
    @domain = Domain.new(params.require(:domain).permit(:name, :url, :domain_uuid))
    if @domain.save
      flash[:notice] = "Domain was saved succesfully."
      redirect_to @domain
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the domain. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

In my view, I have the following:

```
<%= form_for @domain do |f| %>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter domain name" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :url %>
  <%= f.text_field :url, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter domain url" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :domain_uuid %>
  <%= f.text_field :domain_uuid, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter domain url" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Is there something like f.text_field :domain_uuid.RandomGenerate() to randomly generate a UUID ? I know my implementation on the view is incorrect...just need some guidelines on how to get a randomly generated UUID.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [uuidtools](https://github.com/sporkmonger/uuidtools)

```
gem 'uuidtools'
```

simple way to generate UUID and it's look good:

```
UUIDTools::UUID.random_create.to_s
# "7b1fdc50-084c-4c20-a0b2-d76c060ed9cd"
```

Better name for you attributes 'uuid', but not 'domain_uuid', you already in the domain.

```
class Domain
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :url, type: String
  field :uuid
  validates :uuid, :presence => true

  belongs_to :user

  before_create do
    set_uuid if uuid.blank?
  end


  private

  def set_uuid
    self.uuid = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create.to_s
  end

end
```

Comment: Simple way is `SecureRandom.uuid`